# How can I declare and fill at the same time an array of arrays (matrix) using the JavaScript Array fill() Method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to make an array and then to map over it and declare new arrays but failed miserably.

```
let matrix = (new Array(5).fill(0)).map(new Array(5).fill(0));
```

Comment: `let matrix = (new Array(5).fill(0)).map(v => v = new Array(5).fill(0));`

Comment: You only need `let matrix = new Array(this.size).fill(0).map(v => new Array(this.size).fill(0))`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you kindly! Seems like I didn't use map correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function matrix(size) {
  return new Array(size).fill(0).map(el => Array(size).fill(0));
}

console.log(matrix(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the following solution

```
Array.apply(0, {length: 5}).map(function() {return Array(5).fill(0)})
```